# how to obtain unique key for those with non unique value's in R

Tags: r

I have the following data frame

```
fileN<-c("510-1","510-1","510-2","510-2","510-3","510-3","510-3")
disp<-c("account","fail","fail","fail","account","account","fail")

df<-data.frame(fileN,disp)
df

  fileN    disp
1 510-1 account
2 510-1    fail
3 510-2    fail
4 510-2    fail
5 510-3 account
6 510-3 account
7 510-3    fail
```

I want to obtain unique `fileN`'s where the `disp` has both `fail` and `account`

I know I can do the following to get only those with a `fail`

```
df %>%
  group_by(fileN) %>%
  filter( all(disp == 'fail')) %>%
  distinct
```

but how do I get the `fileN` of those that have both `fail` and `account` so that the desired result is

```
510-1
510-3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option would be after grouping by 'fileN', `filter` where the `all` the elements in the desired `vector` is present `%in%` 'disp' column, then `ungroup` and get the `distinct` elements from 'fileN'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(fileN) %>%
  filter(all(c('fail', 'account') %in% disp)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  distinct(fileN)
# A tibble: 2 x 1
#  fileN
#  <fct>
#1 510-1
#2 510-3
```

---

If these are the only values possible, another option is

```
distinct(df) %>% 
    group_by(fileN) %>% 
    filter(n() == 2) %>% 
    distinct(fileN)
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple of base R options

```
v = tapply(df$disp, df$fileN, function(x){
    all(c("account", "fail") %in% x)
})
v[v]
#510-1 510-3 
# TRUE  TRUE 

#OR

with(aggregate(disp ~ fileN, df, function(x){
    all(c("account", "fail") %in% x)
}), fileN[disp])
#[1] 510-1 510-3
#Levels: 510-1 510-2 510-3
```